# Formato de MSMQ

Tags: c#

```
     private void SendMessage(string typeFormatter, string typeLog, int input, string msg, string sglapp, string method, string keyMaster)
    {

        try
        {
            LogMessage logMessage = new LogMessage() {TypeFormatt = typeFormatter, TypeLog = typeLog, Input = input, MessageText = msg, SiglasApp = sglapp, Method = method, KeyMaster = keyMaster, MessageTime = GetKeyDefault() };
            lock (objLockMessageQueue)
            {
                //TODO: Definir el Sentido de Identificar el Formato de Mensaje
                messageQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(LogMessage) });
                messageQueue.Send(logMessage);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

En este metodo hago el envío de un mensaje en Formtato Xml, me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de enviarlo en Formato Json y en simple Texto...  Agradezco cualquier orientacion.

Comment: Puedes usar  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tuTexto) con el using Newtonsoft.Json para serializar a formato Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede realizar una implementacion propia de `IMessageFormatter`, pero podrias usar una implementacion existente asi es mas facil, como ser:

[JsonMessageFormatter.cs](https://gist.github.com/jchadwick/2430984)

[MSMQ Message JSON Formatter](https://snippets.cacher.io/snippet/4136b4e3d886d9cbedd6)

basicamente lo que realizar es una serializacion del mensaje por eso en el codigo se ven las lineas:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, _serializerSettings);
```

y

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None, _serializerSettings);
```

Nota: No se si hara falta poner el codigo aqui, creo que no tiene sentido ya que solo seria utilizar la implementacion que existe

Comment: Justo lo que Buscaba. Thanks!